# Accented french characters in a msgbox

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to write a vbscript that uses **Google speech** to the pronunciation of a message.

I have to save the code into notepad ++ with **UTF8 encoding without BOM** and pronunciation is good, but the display of the message box is not good for accented characters.
How to solve this problem ?

Thank you!

```
Option Explicit
Call Ip_Publique()
'***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sub Ip_Publique()
    Dim Titre,URL,ie,objFSO,Data,OutPut,objRegex,Match,Matches,ip_public
    Dim Message,URLFR
    Message = "Vous êtes connecté à internet !" & VbCrlf & "Votre IP Publique est : "
    URLFR = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=fr&q=" & Message
    Titre = "Adresse Ip Publique !"
    URL = "http://monip.org"
    If OnLine("smtp.gmail.com") = True Then 
        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        ie.Navigate (URL)
        ie.Visible=False
        DO WHILE ie.busy
            Wscript.Sleep 100
        Loop
        Data = ie.document.documentElement.innertext
        Set objRegex = new RegExp
        objRegex.Pattern = "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b"
        objRegex.Global = False
        objRegex.IgnoreCase = True
        Set Matches = objRegex.Execute(Data)
        For Each Match in Matches
            Call Kill("wmplayer.exe")
            Call WmPlaySound(URLFR & Match.Value)
            MsgBox Message & Match.Value,64,Titre
            Pause(10)
            Call Kill("wmplayer.exe")
        Next
        ie.Quit
        Set ie = Nothing
    Else
        MsgBox "Vérifier votre connexion internet puis re-executer ce script",48,Titre
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
'************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Function OnLine(strHost)
    Dim objPing,z,objRetStatus,PingStatus
    Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & strHost & "'")
    z = 0
    Do   
        z = z + 1
        For Each objRetStatus In objPing
            If IsNull(objRetStatus.StatusCode) Or objRetStatus.StatusCode <> 0 Then
                PingStatus = False
            Else
                PingStatus = True
            End If     
        Next   
        Call Pause(1)
        If z = 4 Then Exit Do
    Loop until PingStatus = True
    If PingStatus = True Then
        OnLine = True
    Else
        OnLine = False
    End If
End Function
'*********************************************************************************************
'Fonction pour ajouter les doubles quotes dans une variable
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub WmPlaySound(MySound)
    Dim WshShell
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run "wmplayer "& DblQuote(MySound) &"",0,False
    Set WshShell = Nothing
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Kill(Process)
    Dim Ws,Command,Execution
    Set Ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Command = "cmd /c Taskkill /F /IM "&Process&""
    Execution = Ws.Run(Command,0,True)
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Pause(NSeconds)
    Wscript.Sleep(NSeconds*1000)
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, i solved it like this and you can give a try and post me your feed back.

The script is saved as ANSI and it worked well for me.

**Description :**

This script will display three messages box with 3 different languages ​​with Google Voice Speech.

1. English
2. French
3. Arabic

---

```
Option Explicit
Call Ip_Publique()
'***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sub Ip_Publique()
    Dim Titre,URL,ie,objFSO,Data,OutPut,objRegex,Match,Matches,ip_public,IP
    Dim MessageEN,MessageFR,MessageAR,URLEN,URLFR,URLAR,Copyright
    Copyright = "(2014 © Hackoo)"
    MessageEN = "You are connected to the internet !" & VbCrlf & "Your Public IP Adress is "
    MessageFR = "Vous êtes connecté à internet !" & VbCrlf & "Votre IP Publique est "
    MessageAR = ChrW(1571)&ChrW(1606)&ChrW(1578)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1605)&ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1589)&ChrW(1604)&_
    ChrW(32)&ChrW(1576)&ChrW(1588)&ChrW(1576)&ChrW(1603)&ChrW(1577)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1573)&_
    ChrW(1606)&ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1585)&ChrW(1606)&ChrW(1578)& VbCrlf & "IP "
    URLEN = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=" & MessageEN
    URLFR = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=fr&q=" & MessageFR
    URLAR = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=ar&q=" & MessageAR
    Titre = "Adresse IP Publique " & Copyright
    URL = "http://monip.org"
    If OnLine("smtp.gmail.com") = True Then 
        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        ie.Navigate (URL)
        ie.Visible=False
        DO WHILE ie.busy
            Wscript.Sleep 100
        Loop
        Data = ie.document.documentElement.innertext
        Set objRegex = new RegExp
        objRegex.Pattern = "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b"
        objRegex.Global = False
        objRegex.IgnoreCase = True
        Set Matches = objRegex.Execute(Data)
        For Each Match in Matches
            IP =  Match.Value
            Call NavigateIE(URLEN & IP)
            MsgBox MessageEN & IP,64,Titre
            Call NavigateIE(URLFR & IP)
            MsgBox MessageFR & IP,64,Titre
            Call NavigateIE(URLAR & IP)
            MsgBox MessageAR & IP,64,Titre
        Next
        ie.Quit
        Set ie = Nothing
    Else
        MsgBox "Vérifier votre connexion internet puis re-executer ce script",48,Titre
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
'************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Function OnLine(strHost)
    Dim objPing,z,objRetStatus,PingStatus
    Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & strHost & "'")
    z = 0
    Do   
        z = z + 1
        For Each objRetStatus In objPing
            If IsNull(objRetStatus.StatusCode) Or objRetStatus.StatusCode <> 0 Then
                PingStatus = False
            Else
                PingStatus = True
            End If     
        Next   
        Call Pause(1)
        If z = 4 Then Exit Do
    Loop until PingStatus = True
    If PingStatus = True Then
        OnLine = True
    Else
        OnLine = False
    End If
End Function
'*********************************************************************************************
'Fonction pour ajouter les doubles quotes dans une variable
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Pause(NSeconds)
    Wscript.Sleep(NSeconds*1000)
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub NavigateIE(URL)
Dim objExplorer 
Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    with objExplorer
            .Navigate(URL)
            .Visible = False
    end with
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
```